# Meaning of future conditionals, specific examples

Tags: sentence-meaning, conditionals

I encountered the following example of future conditionals in a book chapter (not a grammar book) and I'm not certain about their meaning.

> a.  If Roman comes to the party tomorrow, it will be a grand success. 
> b.  If Roman came to the party tomorrow, it would be a grand success. 
> c.  If Roman had come to the party tomorrow, it would have been a grand success.

The conditional in example (c) is the one that one I'm least certain about. Without the word tomorrow, it would be a typical past conditional. Here's my interpretation that I hope to have confirmed or refuted.

a. The speaker believes that it is *likely* that Roman will attend the party. 
b. The speaker believes that it is *unlikely*, although still possible, that Roman will attend the party.  
c. The speaker believes that it is *impossible* for Roman to come to the party tomorrow. Perhaps the speaker has just learned that the Roman is out of the country on a business trip.

I believe example (a) is in the indicative mood, whereas (b) and (c) are in the subjunctive mood.

I encountered the example above on page 474 in chapter 3.13 Subjunctive Conditionals in The Routledge companion to philosophy of language.

Russell, G., & Fara, D. G. (Eds.). (2012). *The Routledge companion to philosophy of language (pp. xxv+-934)*. New York: Routledge.

Comment: Please provide proper attribution for the text that you quote.  That means title, author, and publication, or as many of those as are available. Just "a book" is not enough, please tell us which book, author and title. Also, please include a page number or other location. If the source is online, please include a link also. All this gives proper credit, and allows a readwe to find the source for additional context. Please edit the question to include this information. See [**Marking and Attributing Examples, Sources, and Other Quotes**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5785/91457)

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thank you for pointing out the omission. I have now edited the question to include the source of the example.

Answer (score 2):

> - a.  If Roman comes to the party tomorrow, it will be a grand success.
> - b.  If Roman came to the party tomorrow, it would be a grand success.
> - c.  If Roman had come to the party tomorrow, it would have been a grand success.

Sentence (a) is valid, normal, and usual. It suggests that nthe speaker does not know if Roman will or will not come to the party.

Sentence (b) feels a bit odd to me. I eoulfd be unlikely to say this. But I believe that it is grammatically valid. It suggests that the speaker thinks it unlikely (or perhaps impossible) that Roman will come. But it is not safe to rely on such an implication. This form might be used merely to emphasize that the spreaker is unsure. Also, this kind of detail is often treated loosely by fluent speakers, particularly in casual speech.

Sentence (c) ius, I think, grammatically incorrect. the past perfect form "had come" is not used with a future conditional, although simple past forms are.

See ["Future Conditionals"](https://www.englishpage.com/conditional/futureconditional.html) from *English Page* for more detail.